# How to start a tftp server using inetd?

Tags: server, init.d, tftp

I want to start a tftp server.  Here, I am using inetd.

Configuration file for tftp in inetd.conf.d folder contains :

```
tftp dgram udp wait nobody /sbin/tftpd tftpd -l /var/tftp
```

I have changed the tftp folder permissions to 777 and owner to nobody.

When I am running:

```
 systemctl start /etc/init.d/tftpd
```

It is throwing this error:

```
Failed to start etc-init.d-tftpd.mount: Unit etc-init.d-tftpd.mount failed to load: No such file or directory.
```

What is this error is about ?
How can I solve this error ?

Any guidance is greatly appreciated.

Thank You...!

Comment: Lets search for that service file `systemctl list-unit-files | grep -i tftpd`

Comment: I executed that command and It shows nothing.

Answer (score 0):

Working setup

Install following packages.

```
sudo apt-get install xinetd tftpd tftp
```

Create `/etc/xinetd.d/tftp` and put this entry

```
service tftp
{
protocol        = udp
port            = 69
socket_type     = dgram
wait            = yes
user            = nobody
server          = /usr/sbin/in.tftpd
server_args     = /tftpboot
disable         = no
}
```

Create a folder `/tftpboot` this should match whatever you gave in `server_args`. mostly it will be `tftpboot`

```
sudo mkdir /tftpboot
sudo chmod -R 777 /tftpboot
sudo chown -R nobody /tftpboot
```

Restart the xinetd service.

```
sudo /etc/init.d/xinetd restart
```

My suggestion is to move to `tftpd-hpa`

```
sudo apt install tftpd-hpa
```

After instalation edit conf file

```
sudo vi /etc/default/tftpd-hpa
```

file must contain something like this

```
TFTP_USERNAME="tftp"
TFTP_DIRECTORY="/srv/tftp"
TFTP_ADDRESS="0.0.0.0:69"
TFTP_OPTIONS="--secure -c"
```

Comment: Thank You. I have already used the xinetd. I want to setup tftp server with inetd as this is my project requirement.